# Prove that if $G$ is a finite p-group acting on a finite set $S$...

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if $G$ is a finite $p-group$ acting on a finite set $S$ with $p$ not dividing the order of $S$, then G has at least one orbit which contains only one element.

I know that the orbits of $S$ partition $S$ and that Cauchy's theorem guarantees that $G$ has an element of order $p$.  I don't know how to apply the assumption that $p$ does not divide the order of $S$.  I am not sure where to go from here...

Comment: Do you have the orbit stabilizer theorem?

Comment: yes, it is not labeled that in my book (which is horrible), but I found it online and it compares to the one in the book.

Comment: That tells you the size of the orbits have to divide the size of the group. Think about what that would mean in this case, if none of the orbits were size $1$.

Comment: I am not following..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the orbits partition $S$. This the key part. For each orbit pick a representative $x$. This is completely ok (i.e. we're not using the axiom of choice) as our group is finite. Then, let $S_1$ be the number of singleton orbits (if any). For each $x$ not in a singleton orbit, put them all in a set $\mathcal{D}$. By orbit decomposition we can write $$|S| = |S_1| + \sum_{x \in \mathcal{D}} |\textrm{Orb}(x)| = |S_1| + \sum_{x \in \mathcal{D}} \frac{|G|}{|\textrm{Stab}(x)|}$$ Now, since the orbits in $\mathcal{D}$ are non-trivial, each stabilizer is a proper subgroup, hence, $p$ divides $\frac{|G|}{|\textrm{Stab}(x)|}$ for all $x \in \mathcal{D}$. Moreover $p$ divides the sum on the RHS.

This is a useful technique in group theory. Do you think you can conclude from here?

Comment: Can you explain the last term on the RHS?

Comment: nevermind i got it.  thanks!